# La noche cae sobre la ciudad de Naga

Tags: traducción, diferencias-regionales

La noche cae sobre la ciudad de Naga - can I also say ' La noche envuelva en la ciudad de Naga' ?

English translation : Darkness falls upon Naga City.  Any alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting, it would be ideal to know the context of the sentence, because "Darkness" could be translated to "Oscuridad". It could be a reference to the relation between "Oscuridad" and "noche" and "tinieblas". In literature "Oscuridad" has that meaning (sometimes).

Answer (score 4):

Both sound nice.

> La noche cae sobre la ciudad de Naga.

That is pefect. Just there is a little mistake in the second one

> La noche envuelve la ciudad de Naga.

There you don't need the preposition, because *envolver* is transitive. Also, your conjugation wasn't right.

Answer (score 2):

Otra alternativa sería:

> La oscuridad se cierne sobre la ciudad de Naga.

En este caso quedaría mejor oscuridad que noche puesto que [cerner](http://dle.rae.es/cerner) se suele usar para causar más terror o sensación de amenaza por decirlo de algún modo.